# Get time with milliseconds in C++17?

Tags: c++, time, c++17, c++-chrono, milliseconds

How can I get the current time in milliseconds in C++17 with boost or the standard library? I tried using std::chrono:

```cpp
int main()
{
    const auto currentDateTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    const auto currentDateTimeTimeT = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(currentDateTime);
    const auto currentDateTimeLocalTime = *std::gmtime(&currentDateTimeTimeT);

    char currentDateTimeArrStr[100];
    std::strftime(currentDateTimeArrStr, 100, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.%f", &currentDateTimeLocalTime);

    std::clog << std::string(currentDateTimeArrStr) << std::endl;
}
```

But `%f` format is only implemented in python `strftime` function not in C++, and with boost:

```cpp
int main()
{
    const auto date = boost::gregorian::day_clock::universal_day();
    boost::gregorian::date d(date.year(), date.month(), date.day());
    const auto time = boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time().time_of_day();
    boost::posix_time::time_duration td(time.hours(), time.minutes(), time.seconds(), time.fractional_seconds());
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << d << ' ' << td;
    boost::posix_time::ptime pt(not_a_date_time);
    ss >> pt;
    std::cout << pt << std::endl;
}
```

But boost api only give `total_milliseconds`.

I need output like this: `12:02:34.323232`

Comment: You say you need an output like `12:02:34.323232`. Surely that means you need the time in microseconds (to have 6 decimal places - milliseconds would be only 3 decimal places).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So just print the milliseconds from the timepoint...

```
const auto ms = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(currentDateTime).time_since_epoch().count() % 1000;
std::clog << std::put_time(&currentDateTimeLocalTime, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") 
    << "." << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << ms << std::endl;
```

> How can i get current time with millisecond in C++11

You already have current time at `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` call.

Comment: Thank you, But i need a precision of 5 digit milliseconds.

Comment: That's not a millisecond :D And "precision" is not "resolution", for precision ask your system distributor to give you more precision, ie. find a more precise clock source. 5 digit millisecond value, ie `10000 ms` would be equal to 10 seconds.

Comment: If you want the output to have resolution of 10th of microseconds, then just convert the timepoint to microseconds, divide the result by 10 and get modulo 10000.

Comment: Thank with converting to microseconds and nanoseconds i think get what i want, but for example with this python script `datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%s.%f")` i get output like `'20200722_12011595433689.367198'` which is what i want in C++.

Comment: But `%f` is not supported in C++. So... well.. I guess you can write your own `strftime` implementation that will support.

Comment: Just a heads-up: `std::put_time` may not support `%F %T` on your platform, so when testing start small, like `%Y`.